# How do I push the logo up and align the <hr> with the img

Tags: html, css

How can make the logo float up and align with the nav bar it is been push down for the reason I don't know I've tried all padding trick that I know, I also want the img to close the gap on top with the `<hr>`.. So I want the `<hr>` right on top of the img.

[image]

```
<body>
  <!-- Here is the header-->
  <header id="Home">
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class="funBus-logo"><a href="#">Fun Bus</a></div> 
            <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
              </nav>
        </div>
        <hr>
      <div class="image"><img src="/img/fun-bus.jpg" alt="fun-bus"></div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Plastic It's there...look again

Comment: Where is your CSS, and, what are you using the `hr` element for? It is supposed to: *represent(s) a thematic break between paragraph-level elements: for example, a change of scene in a story, or a shift of topic within a section...* If you want a line, you can add a border to one of the elements in CSS.

Comment: please put your css code here  think there is some fault with your css code you are applying.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [border-image property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp)

But anyway, reset the margins of the hr element to 0. By default it has a little margin around it.

```css
hr {
  color: red;
}

.hr-wihout-margin {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Here is the header-->
<header id="Home">
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class="funBus-logo"><a href="#">Fun Bus</a></div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
    <br />
    <hr class="hr-wihout-margin" />
    
    <div class="image">
        <img width="450" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPTBW.jpg" alt="fun-bus">
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I like this approach cause I believe the problem is the user agent style that the browser add to some element (eg: `<hr>` tags or `<li>` tags)

Comment: This a much more reliable approach, <hr> is very browser dependant.